# ADB doesn't detect my Samsung Galaxy S6

Tags: android

I enabled usb debugging, have my phone connected to my computer, the files even pop up but when i go to cmd and write "adb devices" the list is empty. How can i make adb detect my samsung galaxy s6?

Comment: Have you enabled USB debugging in the Developer Options? What OS are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adb kill-server at console then check your Task Manager to is there a an adb process running. After that  adb start-server at console . One more thing firstly download your phones last updated driver to your computer

Answer (score 3):

Ever since upgrading to Android M on my Galaxy S6, the only way I can connect to it with ADB is if I connect it as a MIDI device. My Nexus 9 with Android M works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Download [ADB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/downloads/) and try to install the correct drivers for your Samsung device, should be working.

Comment: Your solution will only work if the OP uses Windows on their development machine.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the driver from the Samsung website, I found for my Samsung Galaxy S6 on Windows 7, I had to select "Transferring images - via a PTP connection" for ADB to recognize my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might need to ensure you are not using a "charge only cable" which does not support data communications.

Answer (score 0):

Just select `midi.adb` in `ADB configuration` under `Developer Mode`. Should detect it now.